# Expectation of a squared random variable and of its absolute value

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

Is it true that if $\mathbb{E}[X^2]<\infty$ then $\mathbb{E}[|X|]<\infty$? If so, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most direct way to see this, without referring to a single theorem, is to consider the set $E=\{|X| \leq 1\}$. Then if $1_E$ is the indicator function of $E$,

$$\mathbb{E}[|X|] = \mathbb{E}[|X|\cdot 1_E] + \mathbb{E}[|X| \cdot 1_{E^c}] \leq \mathbb{E}[1 \cdot1_E] + \mathbb{E}[X^2 \cdot 1_{E^c}] \leq1+\mathbb{E}[X^2] < \infty.$$

The more clever arguments using Jenson's or Holder's inequalities provide a much sharper bound, however.

Comment: While you're at it, $2|X| \leq 1+|X|^2$ gives immediately a sharper bound.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}
0 &\leq \angles{\pars{\vphantom{\Large A}x - \angles{x}}^{2}}=
\angles{x^{2} - 2x\angles{x} + \angles{x}^{2}}
=
\angles{x^{2}} - 2\angles{x}\angles{x} + \angles{x}^{2}
=
\angles{x^{2}} - \angles{x}^{2}
\end{align}

> $$\imp\qquad\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> \verts{\vphantom{\LARGE A}\angles{x}}\ \leq\ \angles{x^{2}}^{1/2}}
> $$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. Apply Jensen inequality to the convex function $x \mapsto x^2$ or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $\Bbb E[|XY|] \leq \sqrt{\Bbb E[|X|^2] \Bbb E[|Y|^2]}$ with $Y = 1$.